# How to use flutter_stripe_web to make stripe payments in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-web

I'm looking for how i can use **flutter_stripe_web** to make payments or a another best method to implement a stripe payments with flutter web.

[image]

Comment: i recommend for now is to direct to stripe and get the api rather use this it might be hard without sample how to use, As i look at the package it didnt even share the git on this.

Comment: @AKMax have you successfully implemented on flutter web ?

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ no, i decided to use a rest api instead to solve this problem. Like : 

flutter web app <---> rest api (stripe functions) <----> stripe

Comment: @AkMax i didnt get you! 
can you please explain how you have done it ?

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ  just use stripe through your own rest api that contain stripe functions.  https://stripe.com/docs/api

Comment: i am using firebase as backend

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ you can use cloud functions to do it. look for stripe cloud functions. i hope this will help you : https://medium.com/geekculture/stripe-integration-with-flutter-and-firebase-cloud-functions-1caac8d70166,

Comment: thank you for this I have already used cloud functions for this.
and it is half working rightnow

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the [example](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example) project as a web app in Chrome browser.

Please note that `flutter_stripe_web` is in very early stage and I won't recommend you to use it in production, instead you should use the standard [web integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements).